# PHP + MS SQL : Fatal error - " Out of memory recode "

Tags: php, sql-server, command-line

I'm on Windows Server 2008 RC2, 64bit 8Gb Ram, there's no problem using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio to extact 200k of entries. But im having a problem when extracting it using php in command-line.

```
$conn = mssql_connect('SERVER', 'sa', 'serverpass') or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on 'SERVER'");
mssql_select_db('database', $conn) or die("Couldn't open database 'Database' SERVER");
$q = mssql_query("select * from trans_bills", $conn);
while ($rows = mssql_fetch_assoc($q)) $r[] = $rows;
@mssql_free_result($q);
mssql_close($conn);
```

and the error come from here

```
while ($rows = mssql_fetch_assoc($q)) $r[] = $rows;
```

i already set the memory_limit and set_time_limit

```
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set("memory_limit", "-1");
```

is there another way to recode and make it reduce the memory usage?

---

### SOLVED

I've solved this by taking a few columns and make a separate process to continue the job.

Comment: Do you _really_ need to read all rows with all fields from trans_bills? Is there no aggregation you can do in the database itself?

Comment: i need to take all the rows, and compare it with another one database

Comment: Added an answer with how to raise the memory limit, I suspect that's the only way you can fix the problem if you want associative access to the data as in your example.

Comment: Instead of adding "solved" to the question, post the solution as a self-answer.